# Unity Editor Animator "Not Set To Instance Of Object"

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image]

Whenever I try to open my animator tab to create a blend tree, I get this error. Am I missing some sort of file? I don't know how it happened, but it seems to make it impossible to form any kinds of blend trees or much of anything in general with the Animation tab.

I have made blend trees before, but now they don't appear at all on the Animator tab. The only thing I can think of that would have caused this is when I transferred my project from one computer to another.

How do I get to create or view my blend trees again...? And how do I fix my animator...?

Comment: Could be wrong but at a glance this looks like a Unity bug.

Comment: It sometimes happens to me also, my solution is usually closing and re-opening the Animator window. If it still persists restarting Unity fix always. It's probably a Unity bug.